# How to send send instructions to class? Can I use constructor array?

Tags: java

I am facing problem in main function of a Java program. I have a class name `HostelRoom` where I made 7 instance variables and four functions, but failed to send them according to this condition:

1. Set 5 rooms.
2. Ask the user to enter the occupant’s information (5 times).
3. After the user enters the required information show him the room selection menu (for example the menu as below)

   - Room 1 --- not occupied
   - Room 2 --- occupied
   - Room 3 --- not occupied
   - Room 4 --- occupied
   - Room 5 --- not occupied
4. If the user selects a room that is occupied show a message “You cannot select an occupied room” and then show the menu again.
5. After the user enters all the record then display the information regarding all the rooms.

Comment: Please post a sample of your code, it would make it more likely to get answers that address where things went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use ArrayList in the constructor of the class. If you have multiple parameters you can use DTOs to pass the data and create list of DTOs in constructor. If you want a list of key value pairs then use HashMap. As per your question is concerned I shall provide you these above options at present.

Comment: DTO?  Are you sure that means what you think it means? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object